# Dar formato a un String en Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Estoy intentado dar formato a un String que se envia mediante un intent a Gmail para mandar un correo...

Esta es la parte de mi código a la que le quiero dar formato:

```
   Pedido = (Pedido + NombrePedido + "/t "  + CantidadProducto + PrefijoEmail + "\n");
```

[image: Esto es lo que se muestra]

Comment: Que formato? Lo que planeas es usar tabuladores?

Comment: Así es, lo que quisiera es que se alineara respecto a Cantidad, lo intente hacer con tabulacion pero no me resulto